# Sending signal from IoT device with button to react-native application bluetooth-ble and understanding services and characteristics

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, beacon

Im making a react-native application which is going to be connected to an IoT device that has a button. I have managed to connect my app to the IoT device and i am getting services and characteristics and other information, but im not sure how to make sense of these and how i can send signal from device to my phone with button click.

I am testing this with a real iPhone device.

Here is the output after i console.log the connected device information:

```
 LOG  Connected to 4C9C0294-C96E-A796-113A-16032707772F
 LOG  {"advertising": {"isConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY": 129, "kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY": 0, "kCBAdvDataTimestamp": 662495861.133707, "serviceData": {"FFE1": [Object]}, "serviceUUIDs": ["FFE1"]}, "characteristics": [{"characteristic": "2A29", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "2A24", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "2A25", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "2A27", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "2A26", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "2A28", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "180A"}, {"characteristic": "7F280002-8204-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "7F280001-8204-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"}, {"characteristic": "A3C87501-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C87502-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C87503-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C87504-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C87505-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C8750A-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}, {"characteristic": "A3C8750B-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295", "isNotifying": false, "properties": [Array], "service": "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"}], "id": "4C9C0294-C96E-A796-113A-16032707772F", "name": "nRF5x", "rssi": -52, "services": ["180A", "7F280001-8204-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", "A3C87500-8ED3-4BDF-8A39-A01BEBEDE295"]}
```

Main question is how do i translate the meaning of these services and characteristics?

Second question is if you have any idea how to receive signal from IoT device button click?

Comment: You probably need to learn the fundamentals of Bluetooth LE GATT services and characteristics or you won’t be able to get very far.  https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/intro-to-bluetooth-gap-gatt/. One you understand this, you need to get some documentation for your IoT device which says what the characteristics mean.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the IoT device or is it from somewhere? If you made it you should know how the button update the device characteristics. If not then I would suggest reading the datasheet of your IoT device see if they specify what each characteristic mean. Or you can download a bluetooth scanner app like LightBlue and look through all the characteristics of your device. And see the data in them change when you press the button.

Comment: The device is premade. When i connect to the devices (i have ordered 2 of them) they only stay connected for about 10 seconds before disconnecting. This happens with all the applications (BLE scanner, nrfConnect, LightBlue). Is this normal? 

When i connect as i understand, if my application is going to listen to an event, in this case "button click from IoT device" then the characteristic will need to have an "Indicate" or" Notify" value?
There seems to be a couple of services and characteristics with read, read/write and one where there is read/write/notify which is what im guessing is bu

Comment: The exception is the application BeaconSET+  which keeps the connection and lets me edit parameters

Comment: I'm not sure why it would disconnect by itself. Maybe there's some message the device is expecting and if it doesn't get it, it disconnects? And yes if the device has implemented the button that way, the characteristic should have a notify property